# Como igualar el valor de dos campos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Que tal amigos tengo la siguiente duda, dentro de una consulta tengo dos campos diferentes de los cuales quiero que uno tome el valor del otro por ejemplo cuando una actividad que tengo en especifico que contiene el id 64, la Horainicial deberia sea igual al HorometroInicial lo intente asi pero me asigna un error cuando intento igualar en el signo = , espero puedan ayudarme Saludos.

```
Select HorometroInicial, HoraInicial 

Case When AA.intAGRActividadKey = 64 Then

HoraInicial = HorometroInicial

Else  HoraInicial

End As vchHInicial,

From Registros
```

Comment: Simplemente pon el campo que quires en este caso HorometroInicial y ya con eso, y remueves el HorinaInicial=

Comment: El detalle que aveces el dato que necesito viene correcto en En HorometroInicial y otras veces en HoraInicial, por eso cuando selecciono la actividad con ese Id 64 quiero que el la HoraInicial sea igual al HorometroInicial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes utilizar la **sentencia update**:

```
UPDATE Registros
SET HoraInicial = HorometroInicial
WHERE id = 64;
```

Aquí se actualiza el **campo HoraInicial** a partir del **campo HorometroInicial** si se cumple la condición especificada en la **claúsula where**.

Posteriormente harías un **select** para ver los cambios hechos:

```
select HorometroInicial, HoraInicial 
from Registros
where id = 64;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono muy bien